# How to create a string with checkbox?

Tags: javascript, arrays, checkbox

I'm trying to get a result that the string will turns to "The person selected A, B, C."

However with the code below, if I checked all three boxes I can only generate:
The person selected A,
The person selected A, B,
The person selected A, B, C,

I don't want the generated notes have 3 separate lines.

```
        var notes = "";
        var reason = "";
        for (j=0; j<document.reason.reasonqst.length; j++){
            if (document.reason.reasonqst[j].checked==true){
                notes += "The person selected";
                if (j==0)
                    reason += "A, ";
                if (j==1)
                    reason += "B, ";
                if (j==2)
                    reason += "C,";
                notes += "" + reason + "\r";

            }
        }



    <form id="reason" name="reason" method="post" action="">
    <table>
        <tr>        
            <td>BPC: <input onclick="ds_sh(this);" name="reason" id="reason" readonly="readonly" style="cursor: text" /><br /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 120px;"><input type="checkbox" name="reasonqst" id="reasonqst" />A</td>
            <td style="width: 120px;"><input type="checkbox" name="reasonqst" id="reasonqst" />B</td>
            <td style="width: 120px;"><input type="checkbox" name="reasonqst" id="reasonqst" />C</td>

        </TR>
    </table>
         </form>
```

Comment: When do you want to generate the string?

Comment: Then move the `notes += "The person selected";` outside the loop and append `"\r"` outside the loop too

Comment: This is a good example of when you can debug your own code. I suggest you learn how to use Google's Dev Tools. They can help you find the error in your logic when you do not get the results you want.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice why Google's Dev Tools in particular and not `whatever-browser-they-are-using`'s dev tools?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca You make a good point that any browser has similar dev tools. My experience is primarily with Chrome and Google Dev Tools, so that comes to mind first.

Comment: It's very unclear what do you want to be generated.

Answer (score 2):

move notes variable outside loop and append single values

```
notes = "The person selected";
for (j=0; j<document.reason.reasonqst.length; j++){
            if (document.reason.reasonqst[j].checked==true){
                if (j==0)
                    reason += " 1";
                if (j==1)
                    reason += ", 2 ";
                if (j==2)
                    reason += ", 3";

            }
        }
notes += "" + reason + "\r";
```

Comment: also the `"\r"`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca thanks :)

Comment: yeah but what happen if he select person 2 the result will be `"The person selected, 2"`

Comment: He can use reason as an array and `notes += "" + reason.join(', ') + "\r";` then

Comment: When I generate the output it showed this:

The person selected[object HTMLFormElement] 1, 2

How do I eliminate [objectHTMLFormElement]?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you a lighter version, you can take a profit of the fact that yours variables and the final values are almost the same, its has only 1 numeric value of difference:

```
    var reason = "";
    let personsSelected = [];
    for (j=0; j<document.reason.reasonqst.length; j++){
        if (document.reason.reasonqst[j].checked==true){
            personsSelected.push(j+1);
        }
    }
    let notes = `The person selected ${personsSelected.join(',')}` + "\r";
```

Comment: Thanks.I should amend the example, it wasn't supposed to be number. I'm trying to create a template for work and I can't put the actual reason out here.